# Broadcast receiver not firing

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm programming an application that will fire a specific method once it hits a certain date / time. However, my broadcast reciever is not firing...i can see that the alarm is set.

my method within an activity:

```
 private void setAlarm(Date date){

        Intent activate = new Intent(this, Alarm.class);
        AlarmManager alarms ;
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, activate, 0);
        alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Log.d("ALARM","Setting alarm");
        alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
        Log.d("ALARM","Setting time "+cal.getTimeInMillis());
    }
```

My BroadcastReciever:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("ALARM", "RING RING");

    }
}
```

My manifest within the `<application>` tag:

```
<receiver android:name=".Alarm" android:process=":remote" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.package.feature.subpackage.arrangealarm.ALARM_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is not firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your code (I copied the snippet and had Android Studio generate a BroadcastReceiver for which I set `android:process=":remote"` just like you do).

When I run the app, the `BroadcastReceiver` fires but I can only see the respective Logcat entry when I select "No Filters" in the Logcat settings (on the right side), not when I choose "Show only selected application".

This happens because you use `android:process=":remote"`. The BroadcastReceiver will run in another process than the "main" application process, so the "RING RING" will appear under another process id.

[image]

Comment: I've updated my question with your code but still no "ring ring"?

Comment: @James Palfrey - I admit I skipped testing before writing my answer because I thought "the only thing which could be missing is the Intent Filter". On the other hand you're using an *explicit* Broadcast (Intent is referring to"Alarm.class"), and it seems that you don't need an Intent Filter in this case. So I'm wrong, sorry. How did I find out? Because after your comment, I finally copied your snippets to a sample app and ran it. Without Intent Filter.(cont)

Comment: (cont) And the "RING RING" is showing up nicely in Logcat. Because the BroadcastReceiver has  android:process=":remote", one does not see it when filtering after "Show only selected application". So you have to choose "No Filters" and there it is. At least in my emulator.

Comment: thanks buddy i would of been running circles around that for a while!